# Using loginview to hide content place holder

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to hide contents in master page this way:

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">

            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <h1 style="color:white"> You must be logged in to view the content</h1>
            </AnonymousTemplate>

            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

but it give me an error when I launch it: I have literal in one of the pages that are in the content place holder
and it says the reference to the object is null.
and I dont understand why.

here is the part that give me the error:

```
  Literal.Text = string.Format(@"
                                                      <table class='zebra'   style=' border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width:100%;-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 1px 5px rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.1); box-shadow:  0px 2px 1px 5px rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.1);' >
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th ></th>
                                                                <th >Team</th>
                                                                <th>Played</th>
                                                                <th >Won</th>
                                                                <th>Drawn</th>
                                                                <th >Lost</th>
                                                                <th>For</th>
                                                                <th>Against</th>
                                                                <th>Points</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                         {0}
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>", sb);
        }
```

sb is StringBuilder

Comment: Can you show the part of the page that gives you error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reference items inside a LoginView. You need to use the FindControl() method on your LoginView control to get them.

Since the Literal object that you are referencing is inside the ContentPlaceHolder, which is inside the LoginView, it will throw an error when you try to reference it.

Here is an Example for finding a control:

```
//Finding a TextBox
Literal lit = LoginView1.FindControl("Literal") as Literal
if (lit != null)
{
     lit.Text = "Value";
}
```

The LoginView is a container control. Thus any controls contained inside the LoginView must be accessed via the FindControl() method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
can you explain more please about the solution?
I'm not very familiar with all the functions

Comment: But the login view is on different page then the one that have literal
so i cant access the loginview1

Comment: Can you post the page that contains the Literal Control?

Comment: I am a little confused. I don't see a literal control on the web form you posted.

Comment: I see that you replaced your literal in the Code Behind file(.aspx.cs) with my code. But where is the Literal control on the form(.aspx). Also, in the FindControl() you are using "TextBoxID", this hsould be the ID of the literal control on your form....

Comment: I;m sorry, i havent been around a computer for a while
here is the litaral. http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1813
and the login view doesnt work - the page doesnt know it

Comment: I updated my code example to use the same ID as your Literal control on your form. See if this works. If not, you might first have to first use FindControl() on the LoginView to find the ContentPlaceHolder control and then use FindControl() on the ContentPlaceHolder control to find the Literal control.

Comment: Is it possible to do it from the page the literal is in?
not the page of the login view

Comment: Can you reference ContentPlaceHolder1 on the page that the literal is in?

Comment: This is because it is in the LoginView. You would have to do Page/MasterPage FindControl() to find the LoginView, then use the LoginView to find the ContentPlaceHolder and then use the ContentPlaceHolder to find the Literal control. Personally I do not like using LoginViews for what you are trying to do. I just make things visible/loaded if user is authenticated or in a specific role.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your question, please mark it as correct (check-mark next to it).

Comment: Thank.at the end i used your visible/not visible advice